# Varying search results for multiple pages YouTube data API v3

Tags: youtube, pagination, youtube-api

I have been using the YouTube Data API v3 to make search requests to get basic details of all of the videos on a particular channel. The channel I am searching contains a few hundred videos so I make search requests in batches of 50 using the nextPageToken, an example of which is shown below:-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId=<channelid>&key=<key>&pageToken=<nextPageToken>
```

This appears to work fine until the penultimate and final searches, where I begin to see varying results. Some of the videos in the results don't have an Id associated with them, which seems a little strange? However, more interesting is the fact that the number of videos which are missing an id varies if you make the same request repeatedly.

An example of the sorts of results I am getting (based upon 100 same searches):-

Penultimate page (100 requests): 60 results of 41 videos with an id and 9 without an id, 38 results of 37 videos with an id and 13 without an id and 2 results of 38 videos with an id and 12 without an id.
Final page (100 requests): 64 results of 25 videos all with an id and 36 results of 24 videos with an id and 1 without an id.

Clearly this will lead to an inconsistent total number of videos returned as I require there to be an Id (which is how I noticed this was occurring in the first place).

I am testing these results in a unit test currently to keep things isolated.

Is there something I'm missing here or is there just a bug in the API?

**UPDATE**

Added the parameter "type=video" as suggested in the comments. This seems to limit the issue to the last page of the search as noted, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Do you get the same results when you append "type=video" as a request parameter? And, could you indicate the channel you're searching, so we can help debug?

Comment: Hi @jlmcdonald, thanks for you input. I tried adding the additional parameter as suggested. It seems that I only see the problem on the last page now (previously I was seeing it on the penultimate and last pages), however, it is still there. The Channel Id I am testing is: UCFHZHhZaH7Rc_FOMIzUziJA. Over 50 test iterations for the last page I receive mostly 20 videos, sometimes 15 videos and very occasionally 16. It could be possible that as the next page token will change for a given search that this is not a valid test? If you are able to reproduce it that would be great. Thanks.